# geoprocessing tool : solving a vehicle routing problem

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-silverlight-api

i am trying to implement a geoprocessing tool in my silverlight application witch use the "solving a vehicle routing problem", i tried to do that in ArcMap it work fine but i have no idea how to do it in a model builder and publish it in ArcgisServer.

need your help.

Answer (score 1):

This 10.0 ArcGIS Server / Desktop tutorial explains creating the model (tool) and publishing:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/#/GP_service_example_Shortest_route_on_a_street_network/002v0000001q000000/

Once you get that part done, use this sample as a starting point to construct a Silverlight application (or you could use the Silverlight Viewer to build an app)
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#MessageInABottle (used to understand an input point and drawing output results as well as calling a gp service)

I realize you talked about a model (meaning you're using a GP service), but there is also this silverlight example which directly leverages a NA Service
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#Routing

Comment: i have already used a GPService and it works fine(drive time and shortest route), but i need to know how to parameter the model builder in ArcMap firstly, then publish it in Arcgis Server.have you any idea??

Comment: Follow the instructions in the first link above

Comment: ditto.. link 1 gives you step-by-step instructions. The only bit I sometimes forget is to use the %scratchworkspace% varaible instead of hardcoding in the model.